# Python unable to execute child python script through subprocess which import functions from another python script

Tags: python, subprocess

I am trying to execute multiple child python scripts from a parent script using Subprocess.Popen in a for loop.

Code in Parent script looks like:

```
    for tab in tabs_detail.keys():
        data = tabs_detail[tab]
        data_str= json.dumps(data)
        #print(data_str)

        subprocess.Popen
        (["Python",data['Script_Name'],data_str,client,spec_path,tab])
```

I am just trying to intially print input args received in my child script which looks like:

```
 import sys
 print('in Project settings' + sys.argv[1])
 print(sys.argv[3])
```

It works fine by printing sysargs..
But when I import my user defined module which has functions to reuse in my child script like:

```
 import sys
 import userdefined.py as ud   # Imported here
 print('in Project settings' + sys.argv[1])
 print(sys.argv[3])
```

Nothing get printed and no error was returned. It just returns `Process finished with exit code 0`

My user defined script looks like:

```
  def readFromDB():
    code
  def readFromExcel():
    code
  def compareDa():
    code
  def GenerateReport():
    code
```

I am planning to call these functions in my child scripts.

Please guide if I am missing something as I am a beginner in Python.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Whats the content of userdefined.py?

Comment: I have multiple user defined functions that read data from excel file, read data from DB and compare it as required and generate report.

Comment: Please attach this file. Looks like there might be something that kills your process, maybe some `sys.exit(0)`?

Comment: No imports in userdefined.py? No raw calls?